# android how to set soapheader in xml parse code?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, ksoap2, soapheader

There is a web service written in .net... I've added a header methods alone. For security. There are four parameters. I have also parse the XML code that i var.burada How do I use the SOAP header

thanks..

my web service header :  .net webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <GuvenlikProtokolu xmlns="http://www.xxx.net/">
      <prm1>string</prm1>
      <prm2>string</prm2>
      <prm3>string</prm3>
      <prm4>string</prm4>
    </GuvenlikProtokolu>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
```

xml parse code is here :

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;      // using.....
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

.......

```
public List<classCust> GetCust(Integer X_ID) {

        List<classCust> list = null;
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.xxx.net/GetCust";
        METHOD_NAME = "GetCust";

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("X_ID", X_ID);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        SoapPrimitive result = null;
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = result.toString();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("ITEM");

            list = new ArrayList<classCust>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                classCust item = new classCust();

                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                item.setID(Integer.parseInt(parser.getValue(e, "ID")));
                item.setNAME(parser.getValue(e, "NAME"));
                list.add(item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Error : ", e.getMessage().toString());
            list = null;
        }
        return list;
}
```

Comment: is difficult matter? :(

Comment: i think insoluble....XML string returned from the web service using the header Is there another method I can parse?